# WPF ContentPresenter content not inheriting DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext, contentpresenter

I'm refactoring some code at the moment, and am attempting to make a custom 'TabControl'. Ideally I would just style the built-in one but there's some quirks to our codebase and I have to keep the existing behaviour.

I've simplified the example as much as I can. `TabControl` displays the *content* of the first `TabItem` (which is always a UI element) in its content presenter. **The content renders as expected, but is not able to access the data context. Can anyone explain why?**

My searches so far have found answers that talk about elements not belonging to the logical tree or the visual tree, or to try explicitly setting the DataContext of the content presenter. These answers haven't worked for me.

*MainWindow.xaml*

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfControls.MainWindow" ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- The binding works as expected here -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Example}" />
        <local:TabControl>
            <local:TabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Some tab content</TextBlock>
                    <!-- The data context is always null here for some reason -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Example}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </local:TabItem>
            <local:TabItem>
                <TextBlock>Some other tab content</TextBlock>
            </local:TabItem>
        </local:TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*TabControl.xaml*

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControls.Controls.TabControl" ...>
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

*TabControl.xaml.cs*

```cs
namespace WpfControls.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Items))]
    public partial class TabControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Items), typeof(List<TabItem>), typeof(TabControl));
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey SelectedContentPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(SelectedContent), typeof(object), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedContentProperty = SelectedContentPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public List<TabItem> Items
        {
            get => (List<TabItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }

        public object SelectedContent => GetValue(SelectedContentProperty);

        public TabControl()
        {
            Items = new List<TabItem>();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Items != null && Items.Count > 0)
                SetValue(SelectedContentPropertyKey, Items[0].Content);
        }
    }
}
```

*TabItem.xaml*

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControls.Controls.TabItem" ...>
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                There is no ContentPresenter in the tab item.
                The content of the selected tab is presented by the parent TabControl.
                This template is for the tab header instead.
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The list of TabItems that are assigned to the Items collection in XAML do not seem to build a visual or logical element tree, so that there is no value inheritance of the DataContext property across this boundary. Try to derive your custom TabControl from ItemsControl or [Selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).

Comment: @Clemens the list of tab items are logical children of the TabControl, by virtue of being assigned via Content. When the content is rendered by the ContentPresenter, it is added to the visual tree. I will read more and try inheriting from ItemsControl or Selector but I don't understand what makes those classes special

Comment: Selector is the base class of ListBox, TabControl etc. It's the most obvious choice for a base class of a custom TabControl.

Comment: You are using the userControl totraally wrong. It's a ContenControl. As such it can only have a single child. Aside from the misconception about how the ContentTemplate works you would have to make TabControl extend at least ItemsControl in order to allow the definition of multiple TabItems in XAML. But then you end up replicating the original TabControl. It would be helpful if you could explain why you believe the original TabControl is not useful. It should be possible to modify the original control to meet your requirements. You really should extend the existing TabControl.

Comment: By the way, the data context is the data context you'd expect. You only override the content by defining the ContentTemplatem, which completely ignores the original Content value. It looks like you got the idea of a ContentCOntrol copletely wrong. That's ok. But why don't you use the WPF TabControl? Maybe we can help to modify its behavior.

Comment: Same applies to the TabItem. A tab consists of a header and the content. This means the best choice would be to make TabItem a HeaderedContetControl, which is basically the same base type of the WPF TabItem. You should use the existing TabItem too.

Comment: @BionicCode single child vs multiple children seems like the key reason to inherit from ItemsControl instead. If you set the `ContentProperty` attribute to point to a List property, WPF allows multiple elements in the content. This works, but EldHasp's answer shows me how much I'm missing if I were to properly handle various edge cases if I shared this control in a library

Comment: The original code being refactored has auth logic determining which tabs should show, and strange pagination logic once there is more than 8 tabs. The page layout is a bit of a god class, and I'm taking baby steps to refactor it. Is it possible to override what tab headers are shown? Not just the template for the headers, there's examples of that already. I need to show a filtered list of the headers instead of all of them, and have navigation logic for that list

Comment: I understand your situation. But I don't see any reason to build a new tab control from scratch. This is a lot of work. At least start from Selsctor. If I were you I would extend the WPF TabControl. The TabItem is used to define the headers. You can use the default CollectionView of the source collection or directly the Items property to filter the items ([How to: Filter Data in a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Not sure what you think of by saying navigation. I guess you mean scrolling? Pagination could be moved to a custom extended TabPanel. Authentication shouldn't be part of the control but you can implement it in your extended TabControl if you think this is reasonable. I really recommend to extend TabControl and add your custom features. Adding features should be enough work. It didn't make any sense to implement it from scratch. There are features that appear to be trivial but take serious time to implement them. Better ask for help if you are stuck with adding your features in the TabControl.

Comment: Doyou want to scroll by a page of eight tab headers? Headers 1-8, next page 9-16?

Comment: @BionicCode I've ended up customizing the TabControl and everything is working as expected. Yes, I'd like to scroll by a page of eight tab headers at a time. There's only a few pages that have more than 8 tabs so I just haven't refactored those pages yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Clemens that you should customize the ItemsControl or TabControl instead of creating a new element from scratch. But I will still show you the errors in your implementation.

1. You set the ContentTemplate for the CustomTabControl. But this template is used for an object located in the Content property. And this property is empty. Therefore, you need to pass DataContext to this property or set Content instead of ContentTemplate.
2. ContentPresenter - is not a ContentControl. Therefore, even if Content is set to the content of a UI element, this content will not have the same DataContext as the ContentPresenter itself.

I suggest two fixes:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376.CustomTabControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Content="{Binding}">
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376.CustomTabControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Content="{Binding SelectedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</UserControl>
```

I also suggest you refactor all the code:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376
{
    public partial class CustomTabItem : CustomTabItemBase
    {
        public CustomTabItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public partial class CustomTabItemBase : UserControl
    {
        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

            RaiseContentChangedEvent(oldContent, newContent);
        }

        // Register a custom routed event using the Bubble routing strategy.
        public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            name: nameof(ContentChanged),
            routingStrategy: RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            handlerType: typeof(ContentChangedEventHandler),
            ownerType: typeof(ContentControl));

        // Provide CLR accessors for assigning an event handler.
        public event ContentChangedEventHandler ContentChanged
        {
            add => AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
            remove => RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
        }

        protected void RaiseContentChangedEvent(object? oldContent, object? newContent)
        {
            // Create a RoutedEventArgs instance.
            ContentChangedEventArgs routedEventArgs = new(
                routedEvent: ContentChangedEvent,
                source: this,
                oldContent: oldContent,
                newContent: newContent);

            // Raise the event, which will bubble up through the element tree.
            RaiseEvent(routedEventArgs);
        }
    }

    public delegate void ContentChangedEventHandler(object sender, ContentChangedEventArgs e);

    public class ContentChangedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        public object? OldContent { get; }
        public object? NewContent { get; }

        public ContentChangedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, ContentControl source, object? oldContent, object? newContent)
            : base(routedEvent, source)
        {
            OldContent = oldContent;
            NewContent = newContent;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<local:CustomTabItemBase x:Class="Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376.CustomTabItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                There is no ContentPresenter in the tab item.
                The content of the selected tab is presented by the parent TabControl.
                This template is for the tab header instead.
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</local:CustomTabItemBase>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376
{
    public partial class CustomTabControl : CustomTabControlBase
    {
        public CustomTabControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

    [ContentProperty(nameof(Items))]
    public class CustomTabControlBase : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ItemsPropertyKey
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(Items),
                typeof(FreezableCollection<CustomTabItemBase>),
                typeof(CustomTabControlBase),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = ItemsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey SelectedContentPropertyKey
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(SelectedContent),
                typeof(object),
                typeof(CustomTabControlBase),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object?)null) { });
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedContentProperty = SelectedContentPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;



        public CustomTabItemBase SelectedTabItem
        {
            get => (CustomTabItemBase)GetValue(SelectedTabItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedTabItemProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedTabItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTabItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(SelectedTabItem),
                typeof(CustomTabItemBase),
                typeof(CustomTabControlBase),
                new PropertyMetadata(null)
                {
                    CoerceValueCallback = (d, value) =>
                    {
                        if (((CustomTabControlBase)d).Items.Contains((CustomTabItemBase)value))
                        {
                            return value;
                        }
                        return null;
                    },
                    PropertyChangedCallback = (d, e) =>
                    {
                        CustomTabControlBase control = (CustomTabControlBase)d;
                        if (e.OldValue is CustomTabItemBase old)
                        {
                            old.ContentChanged -= control.OnItemContentChanged;
                        }
                        CustomTabItemBase @new = (CustomTabItemBase)e.NewValue;
                        if (@new is not null)
                        {
                            @new.ContentChanged += control.OnItemContentChanged;
                        }
                        control.SetValue(SelectedContentPropertyKey, @new?.Content);
                    }
                });

        private void OnItemContentChanged(object sender, ContentChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue(SelectedContentPropertyKey, e.NewContent);
        }

        public FreezableCollection<CustomTabItemBase> Items
        {
            get => (FreezableCollection<CustomTabItemBase>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
            private set => SetValue(ItemsPropertyKey, value);
        }

        public object SelectedContent => GetValue(SelectedContentProperty);

        public CustomTabControlBase()
        {
            Items = new FreezableCollection<CustomTabItemBase>();
            Items.Changed += OnItemsChanged;
        }

        private int itemsCount = 0;
        private void OnItemsChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = Items.Count;
            if (itemsCount != count)
            {
                if (itemsCount == 0) SetValue(SelectedTabItemProperty, Items[0]);
                itemsCount = count;
            }
            InvalidateProperty(SelectedTabItemProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<local:CustomTabControlBase x:Class="Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376.CustomTabControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Content="{Binding SelectedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</local:CustomTabControlBase>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376
{
    public partial class CustomTabControlWindow : Window
    {
        public CustomTabControlWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class ExampleViewModel
    {
        public string Example { get; set; } = "Some text";
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376.CustomTabControlWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Andrew_Williamson.question77744376"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CustomTabControlWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ExampleViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- The binding works as expected here -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Example}" />
        <local:CustomTabControl>
            <local:CustomTabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Some tab content</TextBlock>
                    <!-- The data context is always null here for some reason -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Example}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </local:CustomTabItem>
            <local:CustomTabItem>
                <TextBlock>Some other tab content</TextBlock>
            </local:CustomTabItem>
        </local:CustomTabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: "But this template is used for an object located in the Content property. And this property is empty." Actually the content is _not_ empty, it's being set to a list of tab items via the `[ContentProperty(nameof(Items))]` attribute and the template _is_ being applied

Comment: Regarding "2. ContentPresenter", it looks like I've simplified my MCVE too much. In my application, the tab headers are also included in that template as an ItemsControl so I can't just pass the `SelectedContent` straight through. The TabControl contains auth logic to determine which tab headers should show, and strange pagination/scrolling logic for the tab headers once there is more than eight (this is the part I had trouble with when using the default TabControl)

Comment: You are confusing the ContentControl.Content and ContentPresenter.Content properties with the property specified in the ContentProperty attribute. The Items property, in this case, is simply the default property for populating the contents of an element in XAML. It has nothing to do with the transmission of Data Context.

Comment: It is difficult for me to tell you the right solution, since there are too many unknown details of your task. You should note that the passing of Data Context does not always occur to child elements, as the purpose of child elements may be different. In some cases, it must be transferred explicitly; in others, other containers and layout must be used. In any case, you should understand that the TabItem is highlighted and its content must be selected after selection. In my example, this happens in the "PropertyChangedCallback = (d, e) => ..." and "OnItemContentChanged" methods.

Comment: I've customized the existing TabControl instead. I still have to figure out how to get the pagination working for pages with more than 8 tabs but I'll post that as a separate question when I get to those pages (there's only a few). Thanks for the help